# When changing the homepage/default search in IE, how do I give it my program name to use instead of "Unknown Application"

Tags: internet-explorer, registry

I'm writing a tool that removes the Ask toolbar and Conduit Search Protect.  Once they are removed, the default search and homepage need to be set to a safe site (e.g. google.com).  I can change these settings in the registry just fine, and it works.  However, when I do, then IE informs the user that an "Unknown Application" is attempting to change their homepage and default search.  And it makes the change Opt-In, so if the user doesn't hit "allow" within 10 seconds, the change gets reverted.

I'm fine with making it Opt-In, but how do I get IE to display my program name instead of "Unknown Application"?

And yes, this still happens when the program is signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here has to do with signing the executable correctly.  I was missing a couple fields in the FileVersionInfo struct in the program resources. (ProductVersion and OriginalFileName specifically)

With these fields filled in, and the exe signed, IE no longer displays that alert to the user at all.  (at least on the machines I've tested.)

I'm fine with this result.  But it does leave me curious as to what middle ground might exist that would result in the popup *both* being displayed, *and* containing the correct information.